# Web scraping returning blank results, python code

Tags: python

Trying to scrape job titles from an indeed.com query

Below is my code but I am getting a blank array from my code

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd
import time
```

## importing dependencies

```
URL = "https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=digital+marketing+-intern+-sales+-agency+-talent+-consulting&l=&limit=20&ts=1546381706970&rq=1&fromage=last"
```

## conducting a request of the stated URL above:

```
page = requests.get(URL)
```

## specifying the desired format of "page" using the HTML parser - basically allowing python to read components rather than a long string

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
```

## print soup in a more readable format

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

## withdraw basic elements of data

```
def extract_job_title_from_result(soup): 
    jobs = []
    for div in soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"class":"row result"}): 
        for a in div.find_all(name="a", attrs={"data-tn-element":"jobTitle"}):
            jobs.append(a["title"])
    return(jobs)

extract_job_title_from_result(soup)
```

My output is `[]`

Comment: All good, realised calling their API is the best way to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your method to this:

```
def extract_job_title_from_result(soup): 
    jobs = []
    for div in soup.findAll(True, {'class':['row', 'result']}):
        for a in div.find_all(name="a", attrs={"data-tn-element":"jobTitle"}):
            jobs.append(a["title"])
    return(jobs)
```

**Note:** The problem is in the way you are selecting items with two classes. use `findAll` instead as my suggestion and it will gives you exactly what you want.

```
jobs = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to target more specifically. And you can return the `a.text` to get the link text. Try this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=digital+marketing+-intern+-sales+-agency+-talent+-consulting&l=&limit=20&ts=1546381706970&rq=1&fromage=last"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
def extract_job_title_from_result(soup):
    jobs = []
    for div in soup.find_all(name="h2", attrs={"class":"jobtitle"}):
        for a in div.find_all('a'):
            jobs.append(a.text)
    return(jobs)
print(extract_job_title_from_result(soup))
```

Output

```
['Digital Marketing Specialist', 'Marketing Coordinator (Immediate Start, Casual)', 'Digital Marketing Coordinator', 'Digital & Events Marketing Executive', 'Digital Marketing Manager - Paid Search', 'MARKETING & COMMS ASST, CHOOSEMATHS', 'Marketing Assistant - Graduate', 'FACTORIE | DIGITAL MARKETING COORDINATOR', 'Digital Marketing Specialist', 'IBM Research Australia: Marketing & Communications Internshi...', 'Digital Marketing Manager', 'Digital Marketing Specialist', 'Marketing Assistant', 'Digital Marketing Manager', 'Digital Marketing Executive', 'Digital Content Writer', 'Digital Marketing Manager', 'Marketing Content Coordinator', 'Social Media Marketing Assistant', 'Marketing Assistant']
```